# How should I organize complex SQL views in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reporting, view

I manage a research database with Ruby on Rails.  The data that is entered is primarily used by scientists who prefer to have all the relevant information for a study in one single massive table for use in their statistics software of choice.  I'm currently presenting it as CSV, as it's very straightforward to do and compatible with the tools people want to use.

I've written many views (the SQL kind, not the Rails HTML/ERB kind) to make the output they expect a reality.  Some of these views are quite large and have a fair amount of complexity behind them.  I wrote them in SQL because there are many calculations and comparisons that are more easily done with SQL.  They're currently loaded into the database straight from a file named `views.sql`.  To get the requested data, I do a `select * from my_view;`.

The `views.sql` file is getting quite large.  Part of the problem is that we're still figuring out what the data we collect means, so there's a lot of changes being made to the views all the time -- and a ton of them are being created.  Many of them need to be repeatable.

I've recently run into issues **organizing** and **testing** these views.  Rails works great for user interface stuff and business logic, but I'm not aware of much existing structure for handling the reporting we require.

Some options I've thought of:

- Should I move them into the most relevant models somehow?  Several of the views interact with each other, which makes this situation more complex than just doing a single `find_by_sql`, so I don't know if they should only be part of the model.
- Perhaps they *should* be treated as a "view" in the MVC sense?  (That is, they could be moved into `app/views/` and live alongside the HTML, perhaps as files named something like `my_view.csv.sql` which return CSV.)

How would you deal with a complex reporting problem like this?

**UPDATE** for Mladen Jablanović

It started by having a couple of views for reporting purposes.  My boss(es) decided they wanted more, so I started writing more.  Some give couple hundred columns of data, based on the requirements I've been given.

I have a couple thousand lines of views all shoved in a single file now.  I don't like that situation, so I want to reorganize/refactor the code.  I'd also like an easy way of providing CSVs -- I'm currently running queries and emailing them by hand, which could easily be automated.  Finally, I would like to be able to write some tests on the output of the views, since a couple of regressions have already popped up.

Comment: What exactly do you refer to by "organizing views in Rails"? Perhaps you could illustrate some of them by example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using views in our DB *extensively* and some of them are exposed as Rails models. You work with them as you would with tables, except for you can't update them of course.

Also, some of the columns may be calculated using other columns (different ratios for example) so we don't do it in the view, but in the model instead (ok, not entirely true, we construct SQL snippet and pass it to `:select => ''` portion of `find` call).

Presentation logic (such as date and number formatting) goes to Rails views.

I'm afraid I can't help you with more concrete advice, as the scope of the question is pretty wide.

**EDIT**:

Hundreds of columns doesn't sound reasonable. Sounds like immense amount of data in one place. How do they use it at all? We have web application where they can drill down and filter the results, narrow timespan and time step etc, so they never have more then 10-20 columns in the reports.

We store our views one view per SQL file. Also, you can combine it with a numerical prefix in order to ensure proper creation order (in case some of them depend on others). No migrations there, whole DB layer is app-agnostic.

For CSV, you can create either a set of scripts you can invoke either manually, or using cron, or you can use FasterCSV from your Rails app and generate CSVs by HTTP request.

Comment: I added an update to the question.  Where do you store the code for your views, Mladen?  Do you make them with migrations?  This reporting is a pretty integral part of my application and changes fairly rapidly -- I'm not sure if I like the idea of updating migrations every time the report needs to change.

Comment: I felt the same way about reporting so many columns in one view as well.  To make a long story short, it's for historical reasons.  I'm interested in improving it, but the reality is that people still have to get work done with it now.  CSV generation isn't a problem in itself -- I already have code for it and know how to integrate it into my Rails app.  When you say "one view per SQL file", where do you keep those files?  That is, how/when do you create the views?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't worked much with SQL and views directly, so I can't help you there, but you can certainly build an ActiveRecord model on top of a view, very easily in fact. The book Enterprise Rails has a whole chapter on it ([here it is at Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=thTju-4duY4C&lpg=PP1&ots=nFmsRSwKu0&dq=enterprise%20rails&pg=PA147#v=onepage&q&f=false)).